# PyQt5 [Windows 8- Python 3.2]: QPushButton clicked slot not getting called

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

Below is a code to select files using a dialog box with progress bar, log viewer and close button. Have registered the close button with a test call back slot. But while executing this code, slot function is not getting called.

Can someone point out the program in this code?

```
from lib import window, widgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class FileUploader:
    def __init__ (self, windowObj):
        self.progressBar = None
        self.logViewer   = None
        self.closeButton = None
        self.filePercent = 100
        self.totalPercent = 0
        self.fileSelectDialog = None
        self.__createWidgets (windowObj)
        return

    def __createWidgets (self, windowObj):
        vboxObj = widgets.VBox ()
        hboxObj = widgets.HBox ()
        self.progressBar = widgets.ProgressBar (parent=windowObj)
        self.logViewer   = widgets.TextEdit (parent=windowObj)
        self.closeButton = widgets.PushButton ('&Close', parent=windowObj)

        hboxObj.addWidget (self.progressBar)
        hboxObj.addWidget (self.closeButton)

        vboxObj.insertLayout (0, hboxObj)
        vboxObj.addWidget (self.logViewer)

        windowObj.setLayout (vboxObj)

        (self.closeButton).clicked.connect (self.test)
        return

    def acceptInputFiles (self, winTitle, fileFilters, windowObj):
        (self.progressBar).setRange (0,100)
        (self.progressBar).setValue (0)

        self.fileSelectDialog = window.FileDialog (title=winTitle, filter=fileFilters, parent=windowObj)
        selectedFiles = (self.fileSelectDialog).getSelectedFiles ()

        if len(selectedFiles) == 0:
            (self.logViewer).append ('No Files to process')
        return selectedFiles

    @pyqtSlot()
    def test (self):
        print ('clicked')
```

Comment: remove `@pyqtSlot()`. **Only the classes that inherit from QObject can have the @pyqtSlot()**

Comment: @eyllanesc - Removed. Even after that same issue is seen

Comment: I have tried to emulate what you have done and it works correctly, obviously I have assumed many things so maybe I have not done it correctly, in order to help you I need your complete, for this I ask you to share your project via github or gist.

Comment: I replaced `test` slot with another definition and I was able to see it working.